# Convert RTF (Rich Text Format) to basic HTML

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a database field that stores a comment formatted in RTF rich text format. I am trying to find something that can convert the value to basic HTML for displaying a Vuetify dialog. So far all I can find are tools that convert from file to file. Other than writing my own converter, are there any out there?

> {\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0
>   Calibri;}{\f1\fnil MS Sans Serif;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\lang1033\f0\fs22 Your unit(s) 232323 had a
>   tire issue in 'Dwight/IL': \par \par The Event occurred 10/05/2019
>   08:14:44 AM \par The Vehicle is being serviced by me
>   DWIGHT, IL \par \par Tire Position(s):
>   LRO \par Initial Condition(s) of Tire: Blown Tire \par The Driver's
>   information is dffdsfsdf at +sdfdsfdfd\par \par The
>   Servicing dealer was dispatched at '10/05/2019 08:20:53 AM' \par The
>   ETA is Over 2.5 hours \par \par Refno. is \par Event ID is 343434
>   \par \cf1\f1\fs16 \par } LRI tire, in bay, new tire dr 3434343po
>   issued